# Django, variable {{ }} inside {% %}

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm using Django-instagram for simply display Instagram content on my webpage:

```
{% load instagram_client %}
{% instagram_user_recent_media intel %}
```

This example works perfect, but the problem is Instagram name changes depending on selected page. I pass it via context:

```
def about(request, foo_id):
    article = get_object_or_404(Bar, id=foo_id)
    return render_to_response('about.html', {'foo' : article})
```

It works fine if I'm using it without template:

```
<p>{{ foo.instagram }}</p> --> returns valid name
```

How can I pass my "foo.instagram" like this:

```
{% load instagram_client %}
{% instagram_user_recent_media {{ foo.instagram }} %}
```

Comment: Did you try `{% instagram_user_recent_media foo.instagram %}`?

Comment: For some reason it recognise foo.instagram as string, and trying to find profile with name: foo.instagram

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set`:

```
{% set new_var = foo.instagram -%}
{% load instagram_client %}
{% instagram_user_recent_media new_var %}
```